# Webbrowser.DocumentStream or Webbrowser.DocumentText not working?

Tags: c#, browser, stream, webbrowser-control, linq-to-xml

I can't figure out why this simple lines of code simply doesn't work:

```
// Bulding tree
var declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
var root = new XElement("root");

// Adding elements to document
var doc = new XDocument(declaration, root);

// Salve the stream
var stream = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(stream);

// Update WebBrowser control
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = stream;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're saving to the stream, leaving the "cursor" positioned at the end... and then giving it to the browser, which I suspect is reading from the current location. Try adding:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

just before the last line.

EDIT: Okay, you say it's not working... here's a short but complete program which works for me. Try this and see if it works for you - and if it does, see if you can work out the difference between your code and this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        form.Controls.Add(browser);
        form.Load += delegate { SetDocumentStream(browser); };

        Application.Run(form);
    }

    static void SetDocumentStream(WebBrowser browser)
    {
        string text = "<html><head><title>Stuff</title></head>" +
            "<body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;
        browser.DocumentStream = ms;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok!!! Working now... the only problem I have to solve is that webbroser control is blank when setting its datasource property to an xml memory stream. The Stream actually contains data (I can read xml through righ click -> show source in webbrowser control). Maybe I have to set <html> tag, but I was looking for a better solution...

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but....i was battling this for a while today and it didn't work until i isolated this line of code affecting the web browser control and commented it out:

```
AllowNavigation = false;
```

...so evidently this needs to be true. you can have everything else right and this will prevent it from working.